# Tables and equations in a 2 column paper

Tags: tables, multicol, loops

I am trying to write a paper with 2 columns and I need to insert tables and formulas in it, however, they are not fitting. Is there a way how to make these shrink to fit the page size?

MWE:

```
 WIC is defined as follows:
\begin{equation} WIC(d) = -2(Loglikelihood) + d + ( \frac{d(((log(N)-1)log(N))(N - (d+1))^{2}+ 2N (N + (d+1)))}{(2N+(log(N)(N-(d+1))))(N-(d+1))} )
\label{6} \end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Which document class do you use? paper size? font size?

Answer (score 1):

I would do that with a\multline`environment and a`\splitfrac`(from the`mathtools` package. I took the liberty to delete some parentheses that made the formula hard to read and adjusted the size of some others. Also, Loglikelifood is a function, to be declared as a math operator, if yoyu want to have proper font and spacing.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Loglikelihood}{Loglikekihood}
\DeclareMathOperator{\WIC}{WIC}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
WIC is defined as follows:
\begin{multline}
  \WIC(d)= -2\Loglikelihood{} + d g\\
  + \frac{\splitfrac{d\bigl(\log N(\log N -1)(N - (d+1))^{2}}{+ 2N (N + (d+1))\bigr)}}{\bigl(2N+\log N (N-(d+1))\bigr)\bigl(N-(d+1)\bigr)}
  \label{6} \end{multline}
  \lipsum[3-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. However, did you mean to say that you deleted some parentheses to make the formula *hard to read*?

Comment: @Mico: The harder, the better :o) It's corrected now, thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 0):

using \resizebox{}{}{} could be an option. For tables I would suggest using the table* environment or equivalents from other packages. This environment spans the whole page in stead of just a column.
For formulas you could write them on multiple lines using an array or the align environment from the amsmath package.

Comment: can you give a concise example please?

Comment: Using `\resizebox` or `\scalebox` should be done only as a last, desperate measure.